# Good way to rank/sort data that falls in the lower range

Tags: r, distributions, mean

I have a bunch of data like this:

```
P1 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
P2 [5, 8, 10, 12, 20]
P3 [10, 201, 440]
P4 [1, 2, 10]
P5 [1, 2]
```

Right now it's ranked by the size of its data set (as shown above), so values that are heavily represented on the chart are on top e.g., P1 has the most)

I'm trying to rank this data so that it favors those that have lower values in data set. So for instance P5 (with low values) would be pushed higher than it's now.

Also, P2 could be ranked higher because although it has less values than P1, the values are mostly in the higher range.

Basically I want the data to be sorted by the size of it and its overall tendency to have lower values.

I can average it all out but I don't wanna give weight to data with small set (e.g., 1 or 2 values)

So something like this would be nice (guessing):

```
P1 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
P5 [1, 2]
P4 [1, 2, 10]
P2 [1, 5, 8, 10, 12, 20]
P3 [10, 201, 440, 500]
```

I'm looking for an R solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take the average of each row, divide by its length, and order the rows by that value, it produces the results you wanted:

```
> ranks <- unlist(lapply(p,mean))/unlist(lapply(p,length))
> ranks
        P1         P2         P3         P4         P5 
 0.5679012  2.2000000 72.3333333  1.4444444  0.7500000 
> p[order(ranks)]
$P1
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10

$P5
[1] 1 2

$P4
[1]  1  2 10

$P2
[1]  5  8 10 12 20

$P3
[1]  10 201 440`
```

Comment: if you use sapply, you won't need to use unlist